# Plotting multiple columns of a dataset

Tags: r, graph

I have a data frame that looks like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpXk0.png) and I am trying to create a line graph with the x axis as the condition (D1, D2, D3Ant etc.), and the y axis plotting the data with individual lines for each Cdx1, Cdx2 and Cdx4. I am trying to use ggplot, however I am yet to get any success.

Can anyone give any help/examples, I have a feeling I have to combine the Cdx1, Cdx2 and Cdx4 values but I am unsure.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and provide at least a sample of your data using `dput(head(dataframe, 15))`. Also, read up on the `mplot()` function in the R manual (?mplot) since that seems to be what you are trying to do.

Comment: See for a reproducible example as described by dcarlson: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example